# Find objects in array by some inside property

Tags: javascript

I've an array of objects and I need to find objects with some property.

My array:

```
[
  {
    "lineItems": [
      {
        "id": "92477254-088f-4b6d-bb87-ba670b427eec",
        "distributionChannel": {
          "id": "9c5b1a2a-52dd-4cef-b914-94d2332c5c4f",
          "key": "buyChannel"
        }
        "__typename": "LineItem"
      }
    ],
    "id": "ef6ab2b4-538d-4490-a491-1db561101590",
    "__typename": "Order"
  },
  {
    "lineItems": [
      {
        "id": "93041518-7766-4625-a596-567d41606db9",
        "distributionChannel": {
          "id": "9c5b1a2a-52dd-4cef-b914-94d2332c5c4f",
          "key": "sellChannel"
        }
        "__typename": "LineItem"
      }
    ],
    "id": "06814bde-89a8-4009-a8af-87e031dd10ef",
    "__typename": "Order"
  },
  {
    "lineItems": [
      {
        "id": "81b9aa6c-c631-429b-8227-f21100968720",
        "distributionChannel": {
          "id": "002f67cb-7f2e-48d2-a164-01b2857fcc59",
          "key": "sellChannel"
        },
        "__typename": "LineItem"
      },
      {
        "id": "003797a0-3142-4162-849b-3f0661e3aff5",
        "distributionChannel": {
          "id": "002f67cb-7f2e-48d2-a164-01b2857fcc59",
          "key": "sellChannel"
        }
        "__typename": "LineItem"
      }
    ],
    "id": "631b9945-c30e-4c92-9a01-7635988c7c78",
    "__typename": "Order"
  }
]
```

I need to search for objects which have `distributionChannel.key === 'sellChannel'`, which is inside `lineItems`.

Expected output:

```
[
  {
    "lineItems": [
      {
        "id": "93041518-7766-4625-a596-567d41606db9",
        "distributionChannel": {
          "id": "9c5b1a2a-52dd-4cef-b914-94d2332c5c4f",
          "key": "sellChannel"
        }
        "__typename": "LineItem"
      }
    ],
    "id": "06814bde-89a8-4009-a8af-87e031dd10ef",
    "__typename": "Order"
  },
  {
    "lineItems": [
      {
        "id": "81b9aa6c-c631-429b-8227-f21100968720",
        "distributionChannel": {
          "id": "002f67cb-7f2e-48d2-a164-01b2857fcc59",
          "key": "sellChannel"
        },
        "__typename": "LineItem"
      },
      {
        "id": "003797a0-3142-4162-849b-3f0661e3aff5",
        "distributionChannel": {
          "id": "002f67cb-7f2e-48d2-a164-01b2857fcc59",
          "key": "sellChannel"
        }
        "__typename": "LineItem"
      }
    ],
    "id": "631b9945-c30e-4c92-9a01-7635988c7c78",
    "__typename": "Order"
  }
]
```

Any ideas how can I handle it?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the original array based on which elements contain list items where [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) have a distribution key equal to sellChannel:

```js
const results = arr.filter(el => 
  el.lineItems.some(li => 
    li.distributionChannel.key === 'sellChannel'))
```

Note that if any line items contain both sellChannel and buyChannel entries, they will also be returned.